# Keep/ be quiet in order to ask someone to stop talking

Tags: word-usage

When someone  is talking a lot and I want that person to stop talking, can I use:

> Please keep/be quiet.

Why am I confused? Because someone  told me that "keep quiet" is used to ask someone to remain quiet while they still are, that is, continue that state to "remaining quiet". So is the use of "keep quiet" natural to ask them to stop talking?

Comment: Someone told you wrong. It's perfectly natural (though usually a bit impolite) to say ***Please keep quiet**!* regardless of whether the addressee is *currently* making any noise or not. But exactly the same applies to ***Please be quiet**!*, so you can just choose whichever you like.

Comment: Usually my teachers use this phrase as ***Please keep "it" quiet!*** I do not know what the difference is so may be @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica can explain more..

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: Yeah - *Keep it quite!* and *Keep it down!* are both common expressions for the "teacher + unruly class" context. Including the word "it" there (which you *could* interpret as referring to "the noise, the volume", but we might call it a "non-referential" usage like ***It's** raining*) is at least *slightly* "colloquial". I wouldn't be surprised to hear a British judge say "Please keep quiet" to members of the public in the gallery during a trial, but I *would* be a bit surprised if he included "it" there.

Comment: (btw - "it" is ***optional*** before "quiet" above, but it ***has*** to be there if you use "down".)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica so "quite down" is not idiomatic? I couldn't understand what you meant with "down".

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: I never mentioned ***Quiet down**!* (and there is no imperative ***Quite** down!*). I'm not sure, but I think idiomatic (but "syntactically invalid") ***Quiet down**!* would have derived from *[You] **Quieten** down!* But I wouldn't spend any time on that one if I were you. Just note that *Keep it quite!* and *Keep it down!* are equivalent, interchangeable, and *always* informal, whereas *Keep quiet!* without "it" might occur in a more formal context.

Comment: ...Also note another usage. If you've just told someone something [*in confidence*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--confidence#:~:text=Privately%2C%20on%20condition%20that%20what,see%20take%20into%20one's%20confidence.), you might say *Keep it quiet!* with the meaning *Keep it a **secret**. Don't talk about it with other people.*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I see what you mean now! "Keep down!" is not referring to anything and makes no sense without "it" and thank you for the other usages of things being kept in a way we like.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever told you that "Keep quiet!: means "remain silent!" while "Be quiet!" means "Become silent" was mistaken. These are idioms, and they are used interchangeably. Each means "Become and remain silent!" Adding a "please" does not change the meaning significantly, but makes it more polite. (Depending on the tone of voice used, adding "please" can actually make these **more** emphatic.)

The related "Keep it down" (mentioned in the comments) suggests reducing the noise level, but not all the way to silence. Otherwise, it has about the same meaning, and a "please" can also be added here.

(By the way "keep down!", also mentioned in comments, has nothing to do with noise. It is a command to crouch or lie flat so as to avoid danger from explosions or gunfire.)

"Shut up!" means to stop talking, and is most often addressed to an individual, not a group. It is perhaps even less polite than "Be Quiet!"

"Less noise please" is more moderate and more polite. "Could we have some quiet, please?"  aims at silence, but is more polite than "Be quiet!" There are various other command with very similar meanings, such as "Silence!", "Quiet!", "Not a sound!", and "Shhhh!".

Answer (score 0):

### In this context, the word "keep" does not mean "continue to" but "adhere to."

We would also say "keep watch" or "keep the faith." In all three of these examples, what the person is (or was) doing is not considered. It's a command that, regardless of the case, the person *should* do something.